# Upload Image onclick on Multiple mask Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

Once user click on Mask image, we are allowing user to upload custom image, this is working fine if there is single mask image : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/jJBVON

**Requirement** :

but if there are multiple mask images, then also user should be able to upload **custom images on all mask images** [ something like https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/rRmYPr ]  , but right now its working only for single image....

2 images codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/xBLrjY

8 images codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ywMVOY

```js
var mask;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#fileup').click();
        }, 20)
    });



    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }



    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                }
            });

            fileup.onchange = function() {
                mask.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
            };
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
            var img = new Image();
            evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
            evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {

                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {
background: black;
}

.container {
 background: black;
  position: relative;
 
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

[video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WscFBjtErvSWT-8f5Yc1ufTVUCON_0vR/view)

**Edit**

I tried as Static way : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/xBLrjY , here for 2 images, i included 2 `<input type="file"  >` , for 3 images i may need to add 3 input files , is it possible to fix the number of  or is there any other dynamic hack, so that it will work for any number of mask images ?

Comment: IF SUITABLE, You can achieve this easily in fabric JS, It also works on `<canvas>`

Comment: @harishsharma also is it possible to upload image only when we click on `transparent part` [  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxc5n.png  ] through fabric .js ? if we click on Non- Transparent, than i dont want to upload image ?

Comment: Prepared an example, check if it suits, `https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drvVKq`

Comment: You can check some examples here also, `http://fabricjs.com/customization`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189598/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-harish-sharma).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working solution.I just update the way how you are getting data . I saved all masks in an array . Than look for the array associated to the target click

```
    var mask;
var target;
let jsonData = {
  "path" : " UNEVENSHAPES\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "UNEVENSHAPES",
    "date" : "Uncalibrated",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "UNEVENSHAPES",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "rectangle1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 20,
          "height" : 377,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 377,
              "src" : "d15ad70281961be451263b418a07798b_frame0.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 218,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 52,
              "y" : 257,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 215,
          "width" : 218,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 191,
          "height" : 120,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 120,
              "src" : "2b5d28d0439bc3ce1d856e6c4e5607be_frame1.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 268,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 115,
              "y" : 43,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 472,
          "width" : 268,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic2"
        },
        {
          "x" : 414,
          "height" : 302,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 302,
              "src" : "52c93b6e0a0ffeeb670d0981f89f7fa5_frame2.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 178,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic3"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 69,
              "y" : 182,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse3"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 290,
          "width" : 178,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic3"
        },
        {
          "x" : 374,
          "height" : 377,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 377,
              "src" : "e92f354018aa8f7e6d279601a868a6b2_frame3.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 218,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic4"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 129,
              "y" : 60,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse4"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 20,
          "width" : 218,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic4"
        },
        {
          "x" : 150,
          "height" : 120,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 120,
              "src" : "010054750abb290d1bd7fcecfab60524_frame4.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 269,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic5"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 103,
              "y" : 15,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse5"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 20,
          "width" : 269,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic5"
        },
        {
          "x" : 20,
          "height" : 302,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 302,
              "src" : "e7a5874b58376883adbeafea7ce5e572_frame5.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 176,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic6"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 50,
              "y" : 68,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse6"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 20,
          "width" : 176,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic6"
        },
        {
          "x" : 222,
          "height" : 335,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 335,
              "src" : "591743efa89d8ee936a6d660d52e82b2_frame6.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 265,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic7"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 126,
              "y" : 114,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse7"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 123,
          "width" : 265,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic7"
        },
        {
          "x" : 123,
          "height" : 334,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 334,
              "src" : "22997a60cf61d7b59e92620b86ab86d6_frame7.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 264,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_pic8"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "27 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 73,
              "y" : 167,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse8"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 155,
          "width" : 264,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_pic8"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "unevenshape04"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {


    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        var res =  e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#fileup').click();
        }, 20)


    });


    function getAllSrc(layers){
  let arr = [];
  layers.forEach(layer => {
    if(layer.src){
      arr.push({src: layer.src, x: layer.x , y: layer.y});
    }
    else if(layer.layers){
      let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
      if(newArr.length > 0){
        newArr.forEach(({src, x,y}) =>{
          arr.push({src, x: (layer.x + x) , y: (layer.y + y)   });
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return arr;
}



    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

    /*  
        let layer1 = data.layers;   
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;

    */  
        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];
    //    for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
          for (let {src, x,y} of arr) { 

          //  var x = layer2[i].x;
          //  var y = layer2[i].y;
          //  var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });

                },
                id : counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {
                // get the element associated to it.
                let mask2 = table[target];
                mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
            };
            counter++;
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready
// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
            var img = new Image();
        evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
        evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');           
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });                 
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
        console.log("load");
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {

                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Images are uploading on all the masks now, but there is one issue if there are overlapped mask images : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/rRYqGQ

Comment: steps to reproduce : click on 2nd mask [ `overlapped part - top_left` ] & upload image , then first time, image will upload on 1st mask, if we upload again , than it will upload on 2nd mask

Comment: Here is [video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B4NZWn-wWRgbOHNS5mev67S12cFTLeOy/view)

Comment: I am not able to write in the discussion anymore i can only read. regarding what you said it is about . Because the space where to put icons is bigger than the mask . So they can be overlapped

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using canvas elements for the actual drawings, we can take advantage of that:

```
$('.container').click(function(e) {
  var elements = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  elements.some(element => {
    if(!element.getContext) return false;
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var x = e.pageX - rect.left;
    var y = e.pageY - rect.top;
    var pixel = element.getContext('2d').getImageData(x,y,1,1).data;
    if(pixel[3] === 255) {
      setTimeout(() => {
          $('#fileup').click();
      }, 20);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

`clientX` and `clientY` are the coordinates of the click relative to the client area (the area of the page currently visible in the browser). Using these with `document.elementsFromPoint()` gives us all the elements that were under the click location.

Then we scan through all the found elements, checking if they have the property `getContext`. `.some()` lets us iterate through the array of elements while also letting us terminate early if we choose. We test for `getContext` to see if it's a canvas element and, if it's not, we can skip it.

If it is a canvas, we can move on to the next step. `getContext('2d')` grabs the canvas' drawing context from which we can pull raw pixel data via `getImageData()`.

`pageX` and `pageY` from the event are the click coordinates relative to the whole page. `getBoundingClientRect()` gets us the element's location relative to the page. Combining those gives us the coordinate of the click relative to the element. We use that in `getImageData()` to grab the canvas pixel data at the click location in that canvas.

Pixel data is interleaved red, blue, green, and alpha (opacity) values, ranging from 0 to 255 for each. Since we grabbed a single pixel, it will have 4 values, the last one being alpha. We can then use that to determine whether or not we trigger the file dialog.

If we happen to find an opaque pixel at the click location in a canvas, we can trigger the file dialog and then skip the rest of the elements by returning `true` from the `.some()` callback.

Comment: Thanks, i updated your code in https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/XGRzVq , but i can able to upload image only on `canvas mask1`....

Comment: @vickeycolors Your codepen appears to be working fine for me. I'm able to click anywhere within the white area of the bows and trigger the file dialog, even in the area where the canvases overlap.

Comment: Thats true , sorry i misunderstood your solution, your solution working fine if we click on `mask1` , but my requirement is if we click on mask2 also, than it should upload image in `mask2`.... something like this : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/rRmYPr

Comment: I want to make uploading image as dynamic, because in some files there will be 2 images and in some files there will eight images like here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/ywMVOY , please let me know if you have any doubts on this..... user should be able to click on all 8 masks to upload 8 images....

Comment: None of your original code is designed to handle multiple masks. Even the library you've included is designed to handle only one mask per container. Basically, your ask requires a rewrite of all your code to handle multiple masks. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service so I calling it quits.